# How to Terminate an Application Properly and Save Data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have recently come across the `App.Current.Terminate` method, which I would like to use in an application. Before calling this, however, I need to save some data. For some reason, even though the save seems to be shown as effective, once the application is terminated the old settings are restored. I cannot figure out what is going on. I have a ListPicker, and I am trying to change the theme setting in my application between light and dark, using Jeff Wilcox's `ThemeManager`.

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Tap="stk_Tap">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

...

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ThemeListPicker" Header="Theme"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}"/>
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
List<Theme> themeList;
private int currentThemeIndex;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        themeList = new List<Theme>();
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Name = "light", name = "light" }); //Name subject to change
        themeList.Add(new Theme() { Name = "dark", name = "dark" }); //Name subject to change
        ThemeListPicker.ItemsSource = themeList;

        //make sure ThemeListPicker shows current theme when NavigatedTo
        if (Settings.LightTheme.Value)
        {
            ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex = 0;
            currentThemeIndex = 0;
        }                
        else
        {
            ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex = 1;
            currentThemeIndex = 1;
        }                
    }

private void stk_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //avoid asking the question if the selected item is the same as the current item
            //doesn't quite work properly? Skips when the item is changed for the first time
            if(ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex != currentThemeIndex)
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("The app must be restarted to apply theme changes."", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    var selectedItem = (Theme)(sender as StackPanel).DataContext;

                    switch (selectedItem.name)
                    {
                        case "light":
                            Settings.LightTheme.Value = true;
                            currentThemeIndex = 0;
                            break;
                        case "dark":
                            Settings.LightTheme.Value = false;
                            currentThemeIndex = 1;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Settings.LightTheme.Value = true;
                            currentThemeIndex = 0;
                            break;
                    }

                    Terminate();
                }
            }
}

private void Terminate()
    {
        App.Current.Terminate();
    }
```

Theme.cs

```
public class Theme
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string name //name to use in determining current theme
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Settings.cs //writes key/value pair to IsoStore

```
//Theme - set to true by default
public static readonly Setting<bool> LightTheme = new Setting<bool>("LightTheme", true);
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
    {
        ...

        //Theme Manager
        if (Settings.LightTheme.Value)
            ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
        else
            ThemeManager.ToDarkTheme();

        ...
    }
```

The main problem is that the theme never changes. I set a breakpoint in App.xaml.cs to check the current value of `Settings.LightTheme.Value` on application load, which always stays as true which sets the app to the light theme. In SettingsPage.xaml.cs when a user selects either the light or dark option in the ListPicker, I detect that the value of `Settings.LightTheme.Value` switches between true and false. Immediately after, since the user must select OK on the MessageBox to restart the application, the app is terminated. Upon restarting, `Settings.LightTheme.Value` is true. I am not sure how to fix this?

Comment: could you please share with the code for saving the current theme into Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call  [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) before Terminate.

Comment: Definitely worked! Its `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();` for WP8.

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs the following method can be found. Simply add your 'theme saving' code to this method.

```
// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //theme saving code goes here           
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try. What is the reason for `Settings.LightTheme.Value` not saving the value in `SettingsPage.xaml.cs`. I've only come across this issue since using `App.Current.Terminate()`

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you post the saving code? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, you should force IsolatedStorageSettings.Save() in your case.